# IntelliJ IDEA trouble opening a SpringBoot project

Tags: git, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea, pom.xml

as I do normally (and I've done many many times) I generate a SpringBoot project using SpringInitializr and get the zip file of the project. Then I unzip the file and open with my IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition.
Something very weird is happening: it doesn't import the src folder inside of my Project, but only creates a .gitignore file and import anything except the src folder.
If I try to build the Weird Project using Maven, it returns an error saying that my generated POM is not parseable.

Now , I must say that the pom is the generated one, so it seems free from errors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.pepe.pietro</groupId>
<artifactId>PietroP</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>PietroP</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

This is the project downloaded from SpringInitializr:
[image]

And this is the image of the screen of IntelliJ IDEA after having tried to open it.
[image]
What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the error message shown in the screenshot, it looks like the copy of `spring-boot-starter-parent-1.5.7.RELEASE.pom` in your local Maven repo is corrupt.

You could remove this file ...

```
/Users/allesandroargentieri/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.5.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.5.7.RELEASE.pom
```

... and then reimport your project into IntelliJ, this would have the side effect of forcing the removed `spring-boot-starter-parent-1.5.7.RELEASE.pom` to be replaced hopefully with a non corrupt copy.